# Handle c library error in python?

Tags: python, exception, shared-libraries

If I'm using a lib written in c in python, such as zlib, and I get an error like:

```
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back
```

How do I handle this exception is python? presumably the exception is defined in the c module and there is no exception class to catch on like `except SomeException`?

Answer (score 1):

To call a C function from Python, the C function must be wrapped by a Python function.  For CPython, the wrapper can be written in C with the help of a package such as Swig, in Cython, or in Python with the help of the `ctypes` module.  The wrapper must translate Python inputs to C values, define C output varibles, call the C function, check the return code, and either translate the C output to Python and return it or translate the C code to a Python exception and raise it.

It appears that you are using Python's `zlib`, which wraps a C `zlib`.  It defines a Python exception class `error`.

```
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.error
<class 'zlib.error'>
>>> issubclass(zlib.error, Exception)
True
```

You catch it like any other exception.

```
>>> try:
    raise zlib.error('Error 99: unknown')
except zlib.error as e:
    print(e)

Error 99: unknown
```

To be consistent with the exception naming convention, I would have named it`ZlibError`.